# instantiating a new object or change values of existing object C#

Tags: c#, instantiation, rectangles

I'm having trouble deciding which way to implement my code for drawing a collision rectangle. What is the best practice for doing this. Is it ok to instantiate a new rectangle on every drawcall, with the correct size and location like this:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            Rectangle topLine = new Rectangle(CollisionRect.X, CollisionRect.Y, CollisionRect.Width, 1);
        }
```

Or is it better to create the rectangle in my fields, and then just change the values of the already existing object in my draw method like this, even though the code is gonna be more "messy"

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    topline.Height = 1;
    topline.Width = CollisionRect.Width;
    topline.X = CollisionRect.X;
    topline.Y = CollisionRect.Y;

}
```

Comment: How many rectangles are we talking about? Are you going to be instantiating the same thing over and over again?

Comment: We are talking about 4 rectangles and yes it will be running the whole time through out the game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with first option. If `topLine` is no longer needed after the scope of the `Draw` method it should ideally go as a "local variable".

You need to have a field only when you need it after the scope of `Draw` method.

Answer (score -1):

I would do second, so less job for GC. 
But if you have time, draw several 1000 with first and then second. Check if the performance you won worth for the trouble of messiness :-)

Comment: Can you explain less job for GC?

Comment: Yes. If you create new objects without releasing them, you give work for garbage collector later, what may have performance impact. No idea if creating rectangles is a huge problem tho. I would do performance check.

Comment: I don't agree with that GC will have performance impact. Anyways i didn't downvoted your answer though.

Comment: Downvote is no problem. I only gave my 2 copper without huge researches and articles and strugle :)